# CompanionDeviceService gets destroyed right after creation

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble, android-companion-device

I have simple activity with function that when called displays ble pairing request. After user confirms, startObservingDevicePresence("Some Mac address") is called. That successfully triggers CompanionDeviceService and I see logs that device appeared in range, but right after that onDestroy is called. App continues to run and there are no errors in logs. Has anybody used successfully these new android 12 api's (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing#keep-awake)?

MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
        private static final int SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE = 42;
        private static CompanionDeviceManager deviceManager;
        private static AssociationRequest pairingRequest;
        private static BluetoothDeviceFilter deviceFilter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(null);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                deviceManager = getSystemService(CompanionDeviceManager.class);
            }
        }

        public void start() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                deviceFilter = new BluetoothDeviceFilter.Builder()
                        .build();

                pairingRequest = new AssociationRequest.Builder()
                        .addDeviceFilter(deviceFilter)
                        .build();

                deviceManager.associate(pairingRequest,
                        new CompanionDeviceManager.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDeviceFound(IntentSender chooserLauncher) {
                                try {
                                    startIntentSenderForResult(chooserLauncher,
                                            SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(CharSequence charSequence) {

                            }
                        },
                        null);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                    try {
                        deviceManager.startObservingDevicePresence("Some MAC address");
                    } catch(DeviceNotAssociatedException e) {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

CompanionService:

```
    @RequiresApi(VERSION_CODES.S)
    public class BleCompanionDeviceService extends CompanionDeviceService {
        private static final String TAG = "BleReceiver";
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDeviceAppeared(@NonNull String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DEVICE APPEARED INTO RANGE");
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDeviceDisappeared(@NonNull String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DEVICE DISAPPEARED");
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            Log.d(TAG, "SERVICE DESTROYED");
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you had any luck with this? i am having trouble even getting the Service to start and completely lost

Comment: No, I went back to regular background service and got it working well enough. Seemed this solution was too buggy at that time.

Comment: how did you get the service to start in the first place? i can't seem to even reach that point

Comment: this is the link to my code & question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75695779/companiondeviceservice-does-not-start

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a race condition happening in CompanionDeviceManager, Android 13 should have fixed it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behavior. CompanionDeviceService is only supposed to call onDeviceAppeared or onDeviceDisappeared. It is up to you to decide what to do with that.

For instance you may want to spin up a foreground service for long running tasks or open you Activity.