# CompanionDeviceService does not start

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

i am trying to set up a classic bluetooth companion device implementation but the service is never called whenever a device is in range or even connects/disconnects from it

here is how the service is defined in the manifest and the permissions as well

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_OBSERVE_COMPANION_DEVICE_PRESENCE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_RUN_IN_BACKGROUND"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_USE_DATA_IN_BACKGROUND"/>

<service
        android:name=".MyCompanionService"
        android:label="My Companion Service"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_COMPANION_DEVICE_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.companion.CompanionDeviceService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

and the Service class

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
class MyCompanionService: CompanionDeviceService() {

override fun onRebind(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onRebind(intent)
    Log.d("MyCompanionService", "Rebind ${intent.toString()}")
}

override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
    Log.d("MyCompanionService", "Unbind ${intent.toString()}")
    return super.onUnbind(intent)
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Log.d("MyCompanionService", "onStartCommand ${intent.toString()}")
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
}

override fun onStart(intent: Intent?, startId: Int) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId)
    Log.d("MyCompanionService", "onStart ${intent.toString()}")
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    Log.d("MyCompanionService", "onCreate")
}

override fun onDeviceAppeared(address: String) {
    super.onDeviceAppeared(address)
    Log.d("MyCompanionService", "onDeviceAppeared ${address}")
}

override fun onDeviceAppeared(associationInfo: AssociationInfo) {
    super.onDeviceAppeared(associationInfo)
    Log.d("MyCompanionService", "onDeviceAppeared ${associationInfo}")
}

override fun onDeviceDisappeared(associationInfo: AssociationInfo) {
    super.onDeviceDisappeared(associationInfo)
    Log.d("MyCompanionService", "onDeviceDisappeared ${associationInfo}")
}

override fun onDeviceDisappeared(address: String) {
    super.onDeviceDisappeared(address)
    Log.d("MyCompanionService", "onDeviceDisappeared ${address}")
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    Log.d("MyCompanionService", "onDestroy")
}
}
```

and according to the companion device manager this is how i am setting up how to observe the device

```
private fun startCompanionAppPair() {
    val deviceFilter: BluetoothDeviceFilter = BluetoothDeviceFilter.Builder().build()

    val pairingRequest: AssociationRequest = AssociationRequest.Builder()
        .addDeviceFilter(deviceFilter)
        .build()

    deviceManager.associate(
        pairingRequest,
        object : CompanionDeviceManager.Callback() {
            @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
            override fun onDeviceFound(chooserLauncher: IntentSender) {
                startIntentSenderForResult(
                    chooserLauncher,
                    SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0
                )
            }

            override fun onFailure(error: CharSequence?) {
                // Handle the failure.
                println(error.toString())
            }
        }, null
    )

}
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    when (requestCode) {
        SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE -> when (resultCode) {
            Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                // The user chose to pair the app with a Bluetooth device.
                //val deviceToPair: ScanResult? =
                val deviceToPair: BluetoothDevice? = data?.getParcelableExtra(CompanionDeviceManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                deviceToPair?.let { device ->
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        device.createBond()
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
                            deviceManager.startObservingDevicePresence(device.address)
                    }
                    // Continue to interact with the paired device.
                }
            }
        }
        else -> super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

i feel like there's something missing here that's causing the issue, note that i am currently testing using Android 12 on the device with the app and an Android 13 device as the companion device

Comment: You find any solution for this problem?

Comment: no sadly, still waiting for anyone to pitch in

Answer (score 0):

Call `startObservingDevicePresence` inside `CompanionDeviceManager.Callback()`. Depending on the Android API level, either inside [`onAssociationCreated`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing#filter) or [`onDeviceFound`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing#filter).

Calling `startObservingDevicePresence` in an activity result did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the service starts and onDeviceAppeared or onDeviceDisappeared only when something else scans.

The documentation is almost non existent but I tested on a couple of different phones. I thought it was working at first until I realized a unrelated smart watch app was scanning. When I removed it my app stopped working.

I assumed that the operating system must be doing some low power periodic scan under the hood for onDeviceAppeared to work but it seems to only call as a side effect of either your app starting a scan or someone else's.

For me at least this renders CompanionDeviceService useless.